# PHP & zlib_compress

Tags: php, encoding, zlib

New version of the PHP environment I work with does not have **zlib_compress** installed and adding it is not an option.

There is one legacy integration I need to migrate to this new environment. Unfortunately, it does require **zlib_compress**, specifically I need to be able to execute the following code:

```
$encoded = $string;
$encoded = zlib_compress($encoded);
```

Is it possible to workaround this limitation using other techniques?

I did try the below, but **shell_exec** is not allowed:

```
$encoded = $string;
$encoded =  = shell_exec("echo $encoded | /bin/gzip -fc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling this within `.htaccess` if you're using Apache 2.0 or later

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `zlib_encode()`?

First off, zlib is not gzip.  Those are two different formats.  So if you really want to compress to the zlib format, which is what `zlib_encode()` does with the default second argument, then use the (poorly named) function `gzcompress()`.  If you want the gzip format, then use `gzencode()`.